# I would like to use a UDF in synapse analytics

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse

I am trying to create a function/udf for currency conversions, which maybe i can reuse in a spark notebook, it requires a SQL statement, is it possible to add it to the udf like so? If not what can I do?

Something like:

```
Def curexch(from_cur, exch_rt, exdate, to_cur)

If from_cur=='USD'
    Return 1
Else 
    Return (select excrt from exchange_rate_tbl a where exdate>=a.exdate and to_cur= a.to_cur)
```

Do i have to add @ to the reference of the join?

Comment: This doesn’t help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python

Answer (score 0):

As Suggested by [Skin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772095/skin) and as per this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python) you can create UDF in Azure functions and here are the sample codes for it.

- Register a function as UDF

```html
def squared(s):
      return s * s
    spark.udf.register("squaredWithPython", squared)
```

- You can eve set your return type as UDF and a default return type if `StringType`

```html
  from pyspark.sql.types import LongType
    def squared_typed(s):
      return s * s
    spark.udf.register("squaredWithPython", squared_typed, LongType())
```